# How to get a exclusive timer ID for WM_TIMER?

Tags: c++, windows

I subclassed a control, the control has wm_timer itself. and i need a create a timer for my code, how can i get a exclusive timer id for my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can only get [SetTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644906%28VS.85%29.aspx) to create a new ID when the HWND is null.
If you want a unique timer, you need to use SetTimer without an HWND, in which case timer messages are posted to your timer proc directly.

To send timer messages to a subclassed window you simply have to choose a timer ID you hope is unique.